# Bootstrap-table css not loading after ajax call

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ajax, bootstrap-table

i'm having trouble loading CSS to `bootstrap-table` after I call it by Ajax.

This table is appended to my view by Ajax for each click event fired, but the bootstrap-table CSS hasn't been loaded to each one:

```
<div id="sala_2">
  <h3>Sala 2</h3>
  <table id="tb_sala_2"
     data-toggle="table"
     data-toolbar="#toolbar"
     data-click-to-select="true"
     data-single-select="true">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true" data-halign="center" data-align="center"></th>
        <th data-field="id" data-halign="center" data-align="center">ID</th>
        <th data-field="cargo_id" class="hidden_field" data-halign="center" data-align="center">Cargo ID</th>
        <th data-field="cargo" data-halign="center" data-align="center">Cargo</th>
        <th data-field="quantidade_de_candidatos" data-halign="center" data-align="center">Quantidade de candidatos</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% i = 0 %>
        <% @cargos.each do |cargo| %>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><%= i %></td>
            <% i = i + 1 %>
            <td class="hidden_field"><%= cargo.id %></td>
            <td><%= cargo.nome %></td>
            <td class="quantidade_de_candidatos"> 0 </td>
          </tr>
       <% end %>
   </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-table
//= require turbolinks  
//= require_tree .
```

Application.css:

```
*= require bootstrap-table
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
```

*Observation*: When the page is loaded for the first time, the bootstrap-table CSS has been loaded right. The problem happen when I use ajax to append another table. So, I believe that the issue is the way rails works loading assets.

Comment: Since I'm not answering the question but providing a solution to the problem I'm leaving it as a comment.  Using gems like "datatables" makes loading tables via ajax very easy and efficient.  Also comes with ServerSide processing out of the box for extremely fast loads on large datasets.

Comment: I didn't know about theses gems, I will get more information about it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem calling this method in Ajax success function:

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable();
```

With that, the default methods and styles from the gem were filled out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with loadCss.js lib asynchronously.

git https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS

Usage: `loadCSS( "path/to/mystylesheet.css" );`

Comment: It seems to me that bootstrap-table css has been already load in my file, because, as I said, in the first load of the page the bootstrap-table css works. This JS lib. just append a link tag into the header of the file to be load later, as described in the link you provided. It would make has two references to the same css file.